# Nautilus scrolls results when clicking an item

Tags: nautilus, 20.04

I have a folder with more entries than will fit in a window when displayed in icon mode. If I scroll down to see some of the lower items, when I click an item this display is automatically scrolled, moving the selected item to the bottom of the window. This makes double-clicking to open almost impossible. List mode seems OK.

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit old, maybe you've solved that issue.
But have a look in `dcfong-editor` for `/org/gnome/nautilus/preferences` and scroll all the way down to `use-experimental-views`.
Make sure this is disabled.

I managed to solve this issue this way.
Hope it helps.